# How clear the screen and return to menu

Tags: c++, console

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    int age;
    string gender;
    string course;
    string year;
    string section;
    int studno;
};

int menu(int &menuChoice);
void userInfo(student user[], int size, int const track);
void listUser(student user[], int size, int const track);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int menuChoice;
int static track = 0;

student user[30];

do {
    menu(menuChoice);

   switch(menuChoice) {
      case 3:
          userInfo(user, 30, track);
          track++;
          break;
      case 4:
          listUser(user, 30, track);
          break;
    }
} while(menuChoice != 5);

  return 0;
```

}

```
    int menu(int &menuChoice)
    {

        do {
            cout<< "\n\t\t==========================================="
             << "\n\t\t|\tSimple Student Record Program\t  |"
             << "\n\t\t==========================================="
             << "\n\n\t\t\t\t [MAIN MENU]"
             << "\n\n\n[1] - Search Student\n[2] - Best Students\n[3] - Add New Student\n[4] - View Students\n[5] - Delete Student"
             << "\n\nEnter a choice: ";

        cin>> menuChoice;

        if (menuChoice>5||menuChoice<1)
            {
             cout<< "Please select an existing option!";
             }
    } 

    while (menuChoice>5||menuChoice<1);

    return menuChoice;
}

void userInfo(student user[], int size, int const track)
{
    cout<< "\n\n\t\t\t\t[Add a student]";
    cout<< "\n\nEnter student's first name: ";
    cin>> user[track].firstname;
    cout<< "\nEnter student's last name: ";
    cin>> user[track].lastname;
    cout<< "\nAge: ";
    cin>> user[track].age;
    cout<< "\nGender: ";
    cin>> user[track].gender;
    cout<< "\nCourse: ";
    cin>> user[track].course;
    cout<< "\nYear: ";
    cin>> user[track].year;
    cout<< "\nSection: ";
    cin>> user[track].section;
    cout<< "\nStudent No.: ";
    cin>> user[track].studno;
    return;
}

void listUser(student user[], int size, int const track)
{
    int list;
    cout<< "\n\tName|||Age|||Gender|||Course|||Year|||Section|||Student No.\n";
    for (list=0; list<track; list++)
    {
        cout<< "\n\n" << user[list].firstname <<" " << user[list].lastname <<"\t\t" << user[list].age <<"\t" << user[list].gender << "\t" << user[list].course << "\t" << user[list].year << "\t" << user[list].section << "    " << user[list].studno <<"\n";
    }
    return;
}
```

My previous question was about a student record program got on hold for being broad, so, taking the advice and answers from some users there, I started to search and take action, I'll be specific this time.

So here's the whole code so far. My question is: how to clear the screen so that when you choose an option on the menu, you are then taken to that specific 'place' in the code and once you are done with that part of the program, clear the screen again and go back to the menu?

Comment: depending on your c++ version and compiler, you may have the function `clrscr()`

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to do with standard C++, which has no notion of a screen at all. You'd have to use a 3rd party library (e.g. the Windows API if you're on Windows). Since I assume that this is an exercise where only standard, platform-independent C++ is allowed, you cannot meet the requirement.

What I can tell you, again, is that you are not supposed to use arrays for such basic programming. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: Hey @Chrisytian Hackl!

Yes, this is an exercise, as a matter of fact, this is our group project for our programming class, where our professor gave us a task to program a simple student record program without a database (meaning, I will have to use something to store student data until the program ends or closes)

I will try to use `std::vector` your mentioning, I'm still a beginner so please bear with me.

Thanks for answering my questions.

Comment: @ZeroPointBreak: Arrays are dangerous, because you may already know languages like Java or PHP which also have a language feature called "arrays", even with a similar syntax (i.e. the []) but where the semantics are quite different. So you assume that in C++, arrays are just a normal and safe thing, when you're actually starting to dig around in low-level memory management! :) In C++, when you want to have "a couple of X", you use `std::vector` by default and consider alternatives only when you need to.

Comment: I never knew that actually... I thought there's nothing anymore deeper in Arrays except multidimensional ones, hahaha.

So, I have to rewrite my code using `std::vector` and not arrays?

Comment: @ZeroPointBreak: Exactly. You will find that it makes everything easier (for example, a vector knows its own size).

Comment: Can you point me to the right direction? How will I rewrite my program using vectors?

Will I still be needing the `struct student` that I declared?

Sorry if my questions are starting to sway away from the original topic. It's been giving me a headache for the past few days (thinking about how I will write this code, the logic that is needed, the right structure etc.) Thanks for your help so far! :)

Comment: I suggest you search the web for something like "c++ vector". You will find plenty of examples, and tons of SO questions :) And yes, you will continue to use your struct. std::vector allows you to do anything you can do with arrays, and more. Cases where arrays can do more exist, but they are irrelevant at the novice level.